# How to properly set Angular locale globally?

Tags: angular, date

I'm trying to set French as global locale in an Angular app.

Following the docs, that's what I did in my app.module.ts:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common'
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr'

registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-FR')
```

In a custom pipe, I'd like to use `@angular/common`'s `formatDate` but it requires a `locale` param. Is there any way to get the locale I registered?

I've also tried providing `LOCALE_ID` (`{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' }`) but it seems like I can't use it without injecting it. I'm not sure using `registerLocaleData()` is relevant in that case? (if it is, I'd like to understand why)

By the way, I don't want to inject `DatePipe` in my constructor since I just need to use `formatDate` and it would make my unit tests more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `localeFrExtra` and use it with the register function:

```js
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import localeFrExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/fr';

registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-FR', localeFrExtra);
```

From [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#setting-up-the-locale-of-your-app):

> The files in @angular/common/locales contain most of the locale data that you need, but some advanced formatting options might only be available in the extra dataset that you can import from @angular/common/locales/extra. An error message informs you when this is the case.